# conjectured relations of mock theta functions of order $3$

Tags: sequences-and-series, modular-forms, conjectures, theta-functions, q-series

Given the following mock theta functions of order $3$,found in this [wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_modular_form)

$f(q)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{q^{n^2}}{(-q;q)^2_{n}}$,$\phi(q)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{q^{n^2}}{(-q^2;q^2)_{n}}$,$\omega(q)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{q^{2n(n+1)}}{(q;q^2)^2_{n+1}}$ and $\nu(q)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{q^{n(n+1)}}{(-q;q^2)_{n+1}}$

where $q=e^{2\pi i\tau}$,$|q|\lt1$ and $(a;q)_n=\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}(1-aq^j)$

I propose the conjecture that the following relations hold

> $\Big(\phi(q)-1\Big)^2+\Big(f(q^2)-1\Big)=2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\Big(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{q^{(n-1)^2+2k(n-1)+2k^2}}{(-q^2;q^2)_{k} (-q^2;q^2)_{n+k-1}}\Big)\tag1$

and

> $\Big(\nu(q)-\frac{1}{(1+q)}\Big)^2+\Big(\omega(-q)-\frac{1}{(1+q)^2}\Big)=2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\Big(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{q^{n^2+(2k-1)n+2k^2}}{(-q;q^2)_{k+1} (-q;q^2)_{n+k}}\Big)\tag2$

How do we prove the conjecture?

Note:comparing coefficients on the RHS and LHS of $(1)$ and $(2)$ respectively,we observe that the coefficients are equal

and the identities are both special cases of the more general identity

> $\Big(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n z^{n^2}}{(a;q)_{n}}\Big)^2+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \Big(\frac{x^n z^{n^2}}{(a;q)_{n}}\Big)^2=2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\Big(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n+2k-1} z^{(n-1)^2+2k(n-1)+2k^2}}{(a;q)_{k} (a;q)_{n+k-1}}\Big)\tag3$

with complex number $x$ and $z$,$z\lt1$whereby a transformation($(a;q)_n\rightarrow (a;q)_{n+c}$ or $(a;q)_n\rightarrow (a;q)_{cn}$)  on the LHS results in an equivalent transformation($(a;q)_k\rightarrow (a;q)_{k+c}$ or $(a;q)_k\rightarrow (a;q)_{ck}$)  on the RHS for natural number $c$

Comment: If some reputed mathematician has labelled these conjectures, then (i) they are very likely hard to prove, and (ii) if one has a proof, one would more likely write it up for publication that post it here.

Comment: @Nicco The summation on right side of (1) begins at $n=1$.

Comment: @Nicco The left side of (2) has exponent of 1 on the first term and 2 on the second. You have it reversed.

Comment: @Somos : yes you're right thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @Nicco Also, the summation on right side of (2) begins at $n=1$.

Comment: @Nicco After some computation i realized that if the lett sides are both added then summation begins at $n=1$ *and* if the left sides are both subtracted then summation begins at $n=2$. So with appropriate changes "+" goes with "n=1" and "-" with "n=2". I suggest using the first choice.

Comment: @Somos :Yes I agree,that formulation is much more preferable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The close resemblance of the summation for the pair $f(q^2)$, $\phi(q)$
and also for the pair $\nu(q)$, $\omega(-q)$ suggests that this is a good
clue. In all four cases we next omit the $n=0$ term for the next step.

Using elementary algebra, let $S_1:=a_1+a_2+\dots,\; S_2:=a_1^2+a_2^2+\dots$,
then $S_1^2-S_2=2\sum_{i\lt j}a_ia_j$ and $S_1^2+S_2=2\sum_{i\le j}a_ia_j$.
The two equations are special cases of this general identity using the obvious choices for $a_1,a_2,\dots$. For example, the equation (1) uses $a_n = q^{n^2}/(-q;q)^2_n$.

Comment: @Nicco My answer is a proof of your equations (1) and (2). What is missing?

Comment: @ somos:Is there a standard reference for  this general identity?

Comment: @Nicco A search turns up [Power sum symmetric polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_sum_symmetric_polynomial) in Wikipedia. It is just algebra.