# Do these summations satisfy modular properties

Tags: sequences-and-series, modular-forms, symmetric-polynomials, theta-functions

In this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2408529/conjectured-relations-of-mock-theta-functions-of-order-3) ,I observed computationally that the mock theta functions of order $3$,found in this [wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_modular_form)

$f(q)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{q^{n^2}}{(-q;q)^2_{n}}$,$\phi(q)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{q^{n^2}}{(-q^2;q^2)_{n}}$,$\omega(q)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{q^{2n(n+1)}}{(q;q^2)^2_{n+1}}$ and $\nu(q)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{q^{n(n+1)}}{(-q;q^2)_{n+1}}$

where $q=e^{2\pi i\tau}$,$|q|\lt1$ and $(a;q)_n=\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}(1-aq^j)$

satisfy the following relations

> $\Big(\phi(q)-1\Big)^2+\Big(f(q^2)-1\Big)=2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\Big(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{q^{(n-1)^2+2k(n-1)+2k^2}}{(-q^2;q^2)_{k} (-q^2;q^2)_{n+k-1}}\Big)\tag1$

and

> $\Big(\nu(q)-\frac{1}{(1+q)}\Big)^2+\Big(\omega(-q)-\frac{1}{(1+q)^2}\Big)=2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\Big(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{q^{n^2+(2k-1)n+2k^2}}{(-q;q^2)_{k+1} (-q;q^2)_{n+k}}\Big)\tag2$

and fellow user @Somos answered that the identities are special cases of the general identity

$S_1^2+S_2=2\sum_{i\le j}a_ia_j$

resulting from the [theory of symmetric polynomials](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_polynomial)

But the natural question that arises in the context of modular forms is

> since the RHS of $(1)$ and $(2)$ is related to the mock theta functions by the relations,does it satisfy certain modular properties like mock theta functions?

Comment: Did you show how $f,\phi, \theta,\eta$ transform under the modular group ?

Comment: @reuns : yes for example the function $f(q)$ satisfies $q^{1/24}f(q)=2y^{-1/2}q^{4/3}_{1} \omega(q^2_{1})+4(3y)^{1/2}\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-3\pi yx^2}\frac{sihn2\pi yx}{sihn3\pi yx} \ dx$ where $q=e^{-2\pi y}$ and $q_1=e^{-\frac{\pi}{2y}}$

under modular transformation

Answer (score 1):

Rearrange relation $(1)$ and let $q\rightarrow q^{1/2}$

$f(q)=2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\Big(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{q^{((n-1)^2+2k(n-1)+2k^2)/2}}{(-q;q)_{k} (-q;q)_{n+k-1}}\Big)-\phi^2(q^{1/2})+2\phi(q^{1/2})\tag{3}$

and similarly rearrange $(2)$ and let $q\rightarrow -q^{2}_{1}$

$\omega(q^2_1)=\nu^2(-q^2_1)-\frac{2}{(1-q^2_1)}\nu(-q^2_1)-2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\Big(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{q^{2n^2+(2k-1)2n+4k^2}_1}{(q^2_1;q^4_1)_{k+1} (q^2_1;q^4_1)_{n+k}}\Big)\tag{4}$

after substituting relation (3) and (4) into

$q^{-1/24}f(q)=2y^{-1/2}q^{4/3}_1\omega(q^2_1)+4(3y)^{1/2}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-3\pi yx^2}\frac{\sinh{2\pi yx}}{\sinh{3\pi yx}}\,dx\tag{5}$

mentioned in the comments due to Ramanujan and later rediscovered by Watson(see [1]),

we are led to

$2y^{-1/2}q^{4/3}_1\Big(\nu^2(-q^2_1)-\frac{2}{(1-q^2_1)}\nu(-q^2_1)-2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\Big(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{q^{2n^2+(2k-1)2n+4k^2}_1}{(q^2_1;q^4_1)_{k+1} (q^2_1;q^4_1)_{n+k}}\Big)\Big)
+4(3y)^{1/2}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-3\pi yx^2}\frac{\sinh{2\pi yx}}{\sinh{3\pi yx}}\,dx=q^{-1/24}\Big(2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\Big(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{q^{((n-1)^2+2k(n-1)+2k^2)/2}}{(-q;q)_{k} (-q;q)_{n+k-1}}\Big)-\phi^2(q^{1/2})+2\phi(q^{1/2})\Big)\tag{6}$

where $q=e^{-2\pi y}$ and $q_1=e^{-\frac{\pi}{2y}}$

and we see that the mock theta functions $\nu(q)$ and $\phi(q)$ are related under modular transformation and also the summations as well.

**References**

[1]:W Duke:[Almost a Century of Answering the Question:What is a Mock Theta Function?](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Almost-a-Century-of-Answering-the-Question-What-Is-DUKE/2fcbea36deafaf1e5edc69740c3c56263b753ab1/abstract) August 11 2014